# In Windows 7, can a program overrride file associations not set in "Set Default Programs"?

Tags: windows-7

I am using Windows 7.  I installed a media application (KMPlayer) that does not show up in the "Set Default Programs" list.

Now in the KMPlayer's preferences, there's a setting to associate file types with itself. But when I tried that, I noticed that the files still default to Windows Media Player.

So can I assume that no external application can change the program associated with a file type unless explicitly done via the:

- [Set Default Programs] or
- [Associate a file type ... with a program] or the
- [Open with...] options?

Thanks in advance!

*Btw, I know there are utilities that can help me batch change it. I'm just more curious about the "rules" that Windows 7 has in place regarding file types and their associated programs.*

Answer (score 3):

I think admin rights might be an issue - try running KMPlayer as admin (right click the exe, 'Run as Administrator'), then try to set all associations, and exit - see if it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Try this application, hope it helps: [OpenWithAdd.exe](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/178066-open-add-program.html)